# flex картинка+параграф?

Tags: css, адаптивная-верстка, flexbox

Здравствуйте. У меня мало опыта работы с флексами, и вот я столкнулся с проблемой.

**Задача:**

> 1) картинку и параграф текста поставить на одну строку (фото слева, текст справа)
>
> 2) Соотношение между ширинами - ровно пополам, с небольшим отступом посредине
>
> 3) Когда ширина экрана достигает определенной - конструкция должна разбиваться на 2 строки.

С 2мя параграфами это получается (см. пример), но вот картинка+параграф ведет себя иначе.. как сделать такое же поведение у картинки+параграф?

**Пример:**
codepen.io/AvonavI/pen/gRzqJx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
p{
  width: 49%;  
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  p {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p><img src="http://www.foxtrot.net.ua/medias/mission3.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NTQ1OTV8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xoOGYvaDcyLzg5MDE5NjQxNjkyNDYuanBnfDczZjNjYmNlNTk4ZGVmZWI4YTJkMjRmZWYzMDY4NmI4Mzc5NTE3M2IxYjI0OTNjZmJkMGVkZmE5Yzg1MmQ3MzA" alt="" /></p>
  <p class="two">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo fugiat, maxime dignissimos accusamus veniam consequuntur architecto obcaecati porro quisquam quam ducimus, officia veritatis nulla facere repellendus explicabo. Animi quaerat dolorum nemo eius officiis ipsa vitae illo vero, perspiciatis ducimus porro voluptate quae alias dolorem, voluptatem fugit maxime vel repellat praesentium?</p>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
   <p><img src="http://www.foxtrot.net.ua/medias/mission3.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NTQ1OTV8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xoOGYvaDcyLzg5MDE5NjQxNjkyNDYuanBnfDczZjNjYmNlNTk4ZGVmZWI4YTJkMjRmZWYzMDY4NmI4Mzc5NTE3M2IxYjI0OTNjZmJkMGVkZmE5Yzg1MmQ3MzA" alt="" /></p>
  <p><img src="http://www.foxtrot.net.ua/medias/mission3.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8NTQ1OTV8aW1hZ2UvanBlZ3xoOGYvaDcyLzg5MDE5NjQxNjkyNDYuanBnfDczZjNjYmNlNTk4ZGVmZWI4YTJkMjRmZWYzMDY4NmI4Mzc5NTE3M2IxYjI0OTNjZmJkMGVkZmE5Yzg1MmQ3MzA" alt="" /></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы имеете ввиду вот такое поведение должно быть? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awGMxJ для картинки задайте margin:0px auto;

```
img{
  max-width: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 200px;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```